# Congruence between binomial coefficient and integer part.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

If $p$ is a prime number, prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

$$\binom{n}{p} \equiv \Bigg[\frac{n}{p}\Bigg] \mod p ,$$

where $[m]$ denotes the integer part of a real number $m$.

Comment: It was one of the June problems on my site :) - http://elianto84.altervista.org/problemimain/problemi2014main/30-giugno-2014-problema-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that:
$$\binom{n}{p}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-p+1)}{p(p-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}\tag{1}$$
and that among $n,(n-1),\ldots,(n-p+1)$ there is exacly one multiple of $p$, say $mp$, with $m=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor$. The same obviously happens with $p,(p-1),\ldots,1$. So we get that after cancelling the terms that are multiples of $p$ in the numerator and in the denominator of the RHS of $(1)$, we are left with $m$ times an integer ratio of two integers $\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, since 
$$(p-1)!\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$
holds by Wilson's theorem. Since such a ratio is necessary $\equiv 1\pmod{p}$,
$$\binom{n}{p}\equiv m\pmod{p}$$
follows.

Comment: when i cancel the terms in RSH of(1) i got $m\cdot \frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-p+1)}{(p-1)!}$ i know that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 (mod p) $ but why $(n-1) \cdots (n-p+1) \equiv -1 (mod p)$

Comment: Because if you remove the only multiple of $p$ from the set $\{n,(n-1),\ldots,(n+p-1)\}$, you are left with a set of integers that represents every residue class in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$.

Comment: Done!! Pure number theory!! thank you very much!!!:)

Comment: Your "integer ratio" may not actually be integer (example: $n=7$ and $p=3$); it is merely a $p$-integer (i.e., its denominator is coprime to $p$). Not a big deal, if one knows that the $p$-integers modulo $p$ are isomorphic to the integers modulo $p$, but I wanted to mention this.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $$\binom{n+p}{p} \equiv \binom{n}{p}+1$$

Indeed:

$$\binom{n+p}{p} = \sum_{k+l=p}\binom{n}{k} \cdot \binom{p}{l}$$

For $0<l<p$ the factors $\binom{p}{l}$ are divisible by $p$.

Apply induction.

Obs:It's true in fact for all $n\ge 0$

Also check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem

Comment: Note that this shows that the claim is true for all integers $n$ (including negative integers).

Answer (score 2):

**A combinatorial solution:** Divide $n$ by $p$ with remainder: write $n=ap+b$ where $0 \leq b < p$, such that $a = \lfloor \frac{n}{p} \rfloor$. We now divide the first $ap+b$ positive integers in $a$ groups of $p$ and one group of $b$:
$$
\underbrace{\underbrace{1,2,\ldots,p}_p, \underbrace{p+1, \ldots, 2p}_{p}, \ldots, \underbrace{ap-p+1, \ldots, ap}_{p}}_a, \underbrace{ap+1, \ldots, ap+b}_b
$$
The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{p} = \binom{ap+b}{p}$, by definition, gives the number of ways to choose $p$ of these numbers. Define $f: \{1,2,\ldots,ap+b\} \to \{1,2,\ldots,ap+b\}$ as follows: $f(x)=x$ for $x>ap$, $f(x)=x+1$ for $x \leq ap$ such that $p \nmid x$ and $f(x)=x-p+1$ when $p \mid x$. It is easy to check that $f$ is a bijection (it keeps the numbers larger than $ap$ fixed and cyclically permutes the numbers in the sets $V_1 = \{1,2,\ldots,p\}$, $\ldots,$ $V_a = \{ap-p+1,\ldots,ap\}$). If $S$ is a set of $p$ of the numbers $\{1,2,\ldots,ap+b\}$, the set $f(S)$ is as well. We have $f^p(S)=S$. Consider the function $f$ acting on the set $\mathcal{T}$ of all $p$-element subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,ap+b\}$ (we have $|\mathcal{T}| = \binom{ap+b}{p}$). The sets $V_1$, $\ldots$, $V_a$ are fixed under $f$, so each of them has an orbit of length one. All other sets have orbits of length $p$ (since $f$ does not fix them but $f^p$ does). It follows that $\binom{n}{p} - a = |\mathcal{T}| - a$ is divisible by $p$.